# Position and format frame labels and ticks frame ticks

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, ticks, frame

How could I move axis and tick labels from the left to the right vertical axis, while retaining ticks on both vertical axes, but removing ticks, axis labels, and tick labels from the top and bottom axes?

See the following example:

```
Plot[
  Sin[x]^3, {x, 0, 10 π}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  FrameTicks -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}
]
```

Comment: try `Plot[Sin[x]^3, {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, "x"}, {"y", None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{False, All}, {False, False}}]`?

Comment: Ticks on the left y-axis are also wanted.

Comment: Try: `Plot[Sin[x]^3, {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, "x"}, {"y", None}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {False, False}}]`

Comment: No number on the left axis @ Daniel Huber

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Use `FrameTicks -> {All, {None, None}}` and hide unwanted tick labels using `FontOpacity -> 0` in `FrameTicksStyle` :

```
Plot[Sin[x]^3, {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {All, {None, None}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{FontOpacity -> 0, Automatic}, Automatic},
 FrameLabel -> {{None, "x"}, {"y", None}}]
```

[image]

**2.** Use `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}] `` to generate ticks without labels:

```
Plot[Sin[x]^3, {x, 0, 10 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}], All}, {None, None}},
 FrameLabel -> {{None, "x"}, {"y", None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The left and right axes are perfect what I want, but no ticks and labels are required on the bottom and top axes.

Comment: @SciJewel, please see the update.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Kglr! Always helpful!

Comment: how to rotate the tick labels (-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) in the above plot? Is this possible?

Comment: @SciJewel, define ``rotatedFrameLabels = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] /. l_NumberForm :> Rotate[l, 90 Degree] &;`` and replace `All` with `{rotatedFrameLabels, rotatedFrameLabels}` in method 1 and with `rotatedFrameLabels` in method 2.